# How do I order a variable in an each loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to order the "discussions" by date in this loop. However in this loop the "discussions" will be ordered grouped by their parent "channel". How do I ungroup the "discussions" from their "channel" and order them all collectively by date?

```
        <% current_user.following_channels.each do |channel| %>
                <% channel.discussions.order('created_at desc').limit(40).each do |discussion| %>
                    <%= render partial: "shared/discussions-sub-partial", locals: { discussion: discussion } %>
                <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `channel.discussions` you will only have the discussions from that channel only. You should use

```
current_user.discussions.order('discussions.created at DESC').each do |discussions|
    # do your rendering here
end
```

`user.rb` should have something similar to this

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :following_channels
    has_many :discussions, through: :following_channels
end
```